# Not able to find the image by Server.MapPath()

Tags: c#

Below code I am using but image is not coming, I have checked the path and it is correct.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\Images\MyApp.png");
```

May I know the reason for this?

Comment: You could give `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\MyApp.png")` a try. the `~` refers to the application root directory

Comment: a path separator starting a path makes it a root path. you probably intend a relative path. Plus, virtual paths are usually written with forward slashes (not related to this problem though)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images");
string rootPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", root, "MyApp.png");
```

Add `~` and put the bars `/`